# Calculation of extrinsic curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature, general-relativity

I asked this question first on physics.SE but I got no complete answer so I thought maybe someone here could help.

I'm trying to understand how to derive the **extrinsic curvature** (in order to understand some calculation on fluid/gravity dynamics). But I hit a wall in my progress. I stuck at trying to verify the extrinsic curvature of a slowing-rotating Kerr solution ( *page 94, E.Poisson: A relativistic Toolkit: The mathematics of black holes* ):
$$ds_+^2=g_{ab}\;dx^a dx^b=-f dt^2+f^{-1}dr^2+r^2 d\Omega^2-\frac{4Ma}{r}\;\sin^2(\theta)\;dr\;d\phi$$
where $f=1-2M/r$ and cut of $r=R$ which defines the hypersurface $\Sigma$ on which we'll work on.

I derive the induced metric (with $\psi=\phi-\Omega t$ and $\Omega=\frac{2Ma}{R^3}$) :
\begin{equation}
h_{ab}\;dy^ady^b=-f dt^2+R^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\psi^2)
\end{equation}

But from here on, I stuck. So my stucking points are:

> 1. How can I derive the form of the unit normal vector $n_a$ here and in not so obvious metrics ?(The answer for this problem is $n_a=f^{-1/2}\partial_a\;r$, this means that $n_a=f^{-1/2}\delta^r_a$) ?
> 2. The extrinsic curvature is defined as
>
> $$K_{AB}=n_{a;b}\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial y^A}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial y^B} \;\;\;\;\;\;\; (1)$$
>
> where $x^a=x^a(y^A)$.

***Edit***: Until now I have compute the $n_a=f^{-1/2}\delta^{r}_{a}$ but if I try to compute the components of the extrinsic curvature, my answers are in complete disagreement with the answers from the book. I found for example $$K_{\theta\theta}=1/2$$ which is obviously wrong. The right answer is $$K_{\theta\theta}=f^{1/2}/R$$

Any suggestions? Thank you.